# Group .txt data into dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a .txt file with data like such:

```
[12.06.17, 13:18:36] Name1: Test test test
[12.06.17, 13:20:20] Name2 ❤️: blabla
[12.06.17, 13:20:44] Name2 ❤️: words words words
words
words
words
[12.06.17, 13:29:03] Name1: more words more words
[12.06.17, 13:38:52] Name3 Surname Nickname: 
[12.06.17, 13:40:37] Name1: message?
```

Note, that there can be multiple names before the message and also multiline messages can occur. I tried many things for the last days already to split the data into the groups 'date', 'time', 'name', 'message'.

I was able to figure out, that the regex

```
(.)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(,)(\s)(\d+:\d+:\d+)(.)(\s)([^:]+)(:)
```

is able to capture everything up to the message (cf.: https://regex101.com/r/hQlgeM/3). But I cannot figure out how to add the message so that multiline messages are grouped into the previous message.

Lastly: If I am able to capture each group from the .txt with regex, how do I actually pass each group into a separate column. I've been looking at examples for the last three days, but I still cannot figure out how to finally construct this dataframe.

Code that I tried to work with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('chat.txt', names = ['raw'])

data = df.iloc[:,0]

re.match(r'\[([^]]+)\] ([^:]+):(.*)', data)
```

Another try that did not work:

```
input_file = open("chat.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')

content = input_file.read()

df = pd.DataFrame(content, columns = ['raw'])

df['date'] = df['raw'].str.extract(r'^(.)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', expand=True)

df['time'] = df['raw'].str.extract(r'(\s)(\d+:\d+:\d+)', expand=True)

df['name'] = df['raw'].str.extract(r'(\s)([^:]+)(:)', expand=True)

df['message'] = df['raw'].str.extract(r'^(.)(?<=:).*$', expand=True)

df
```

Comment: You may use `(?s)(\[)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(,)(\s)(\d+:\d+:\d+)(])(\s)([^:]+)(:)(.*?)(?=\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+,\s\d+:\d+:\d+]|\Z)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4ri2M/1). Are you sure you need so many groups? I'd rather use them [like here](https://regex101.com/r/K4ri2M/2).

Comment: Thank you! But how do I pass this into a pandas dataframe? I just want four columns with 'date', 'time', 'name', 'message'. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Use named groups with `str.extract`, see https://regex101.com/r/K4ri2M/3

Comment: Did it finally work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I figured works in my case. The problem was that I was using read_csv() when it is txt data. Also I needed to use regex to build my format before passing in into pandas:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

chat = open('chat.txt').read()
pattern = r'(?s)\[(?P<date>\d+(?:\.\d+){2}),\s(?P<time>\d+(?::\d+){2})]\s(?P<name>[^:]+):(?P<message>.*?)(?=\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+,\s\d+:\d+:\d+]|\Z)'

for row in re.findall(pattern, chat):
    row

df = pd.DataFrame(re.findall(pattern, chat), columns=['date', 'time', 'name', 'message'])

print (df.tail)
```

Answer (score 3):

A complete solution will look like

```
import pandas as pd
import io, re

file_path = 'chat.txt'
rx = re.compile(r'\[(?P<date>\d+(?:\.\d+){2}),\s(?P<time>\d+(?::\d+){2})]\s(?P<name>[^:]+):(?P<message>.*)')
col_list = []
date = time = name = message = ''

with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding = "utf-8", newline="\n") as sr:
    for line in sr:
        m = rx.match(line)
        if m:
            col_list.append([date, time, name, message])
            date = m.group("date")
            time = m.group("time")
            name = m.group("name")
            message = m.group("message")
        else:
            if line:
                message += line

df = pd.DataFrame(col_list, columns=['date', 'time', 'name', 'message'])
```

**Pattern details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?P<date>\d+(?:\.\d+){2})` - Group "date": 1+ digits and then two repetitions of `.` and two digits
- `,\s` - `,` and a whitespace
- `(?P<time>\d+(?::\d+){2})` - Group "time": 1+ digits and then two repetitions of `:` and two digits
- `]\s` - `]` and a whitespace
- `(?P<name>[^:]+)` - Group "name": one or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `(?P<message>.*)` - Group "message": any 0+ chars, as many as possible,  up to the end of line.

Then, the logic is as follows:

- A line is read in and tested against the pattern
- If there is a match, the four variables - date, time, name and message - details are initialized
- If the next line does not match the pattern it is considered part of the message and is thus appended to `message` variable.

Comment: thanks four your help but when i do:
    
`df = pd.read_csv('chat.txt', names = ['raw'])`

`df = df['raw'].str.extract(r'(?s)\[(?P<date>\d+(?:\.\d+){2}),\s(?P<time>\d+(?::\d+){2})]\s(?P<name>[^:]+):(?P<message>.*?)(?=\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+,\s\d+:\d+:\d+]|\Z)', expand = True)`

`print (df.tail)`

I receive

`<bound method NDFrame.tail of            date time name message`
`[11.06.17   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN`
`[11.06.17   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN`
`[11.06.17   NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN`

Comment: @LGR Looks like the problem with reading in the file. I updated the solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found another solution that I will post below :)